# How to reset firebase server to permit function deploy?

Tags: javascript, firebase, server, infinite-recursion

Using `firebase deploy --only functions` I saw an error in my react code and typed control-C to kill the deploy from my Mac.  Now, when trying to deploy again to the Google servers, it gets error:

```
firebase.js -> build/firebase.js
index.js -> build/index.js
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing server-functions/build directory for uploading...
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How can I reset the firebase server so that I can deploy my functions again?  Doing a full deploy didn't help either, still gets same error during the functions phase.  Rolling back deploy did not help, nor did deleting all functions on the server.

Is there a safe way to kill a deploy?

---

Another user was able to deploy, and at this point the error has changed:

```
firebase.js -> build/firebase.js
index.js -> build/index.js
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled

Error: Server Error. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com:443
```

And a subsequent retry, returned to the first error about call stack overflow again.

---

Is there a way to get the call stack trace when the `Maximum call stack sized exceeded` occurs?

Comment: If this isn't a prod app, might start by going into console.cloud.google.com (not Firebase) and deleting the existing functions there, and trying the redeploy. Might also try disabling and re-enabling Functions. If you don't get results, I'd reach out to [support](https://firebase.google.com/support/). Not one I've seen before.

Comment: @kato Deleting the functions in the console did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was my code was causing the crash, by reverting back to the last checked in javascript, the crash went away.